# HTML CSS Class Selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help on understanding the class selector code. Currently I have these:

```
<div class="tt-news">
    <div class="tt-news-top">
        <a class="tt-news-img custom-hover" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/"><img alt="" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" height="168" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px" src="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg" srcset="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg 750w, http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2-300x140.jpg 300w" width="360"></a>
        <div class="tt-news-date" style="display: block;">
            <span>11</span> Oct
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tt-news-label">
        <span>By: <a>cfbt admin</a></span>
    </div><a class="tt-news-title c-h6" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/" style="display: block;">Puppet Workshop</a>
    <div class="simple-text size-4">
        &nbsp; An optional PD session entitled “Making a Bruneian Student Finger Puppet” was held on Wednesday ...
    </div>
```

Im trying to show the **.tt-news-date span** and **.tt-news-label .tt-news-title** on hovering the **.custom-hover**

Right now, I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
var posthover = $(".custom-hover.custom-hover");

$(posthover).hover( function() {
$(".tt-news-date").css("display", "block");
$(".tt-news-title").css("display", "block");
});

});
```

But this will show all of the title and date on hovered. I just need to show the closest to the one's I hovered. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use the [**`.closest()` jQuery method**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use jQuery for something that can be done solely with CSS.

The code below will only show the sections .tt-news-date span and .tt-news-title when you hover over the section .tt-news.

I know it isn't exactly what you want, but it should work close enough that you no longer need JavaScript to do it.

```css
.tt-news:not(:hover) .tt-news-date,
.tt-news:not(:hover) .tt-news-title {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tt-news">
  <div class="tt-news-top">
    <a class="tt-news-img custom-hover" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/"><img alt="" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" height="168" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px" src="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg" srcset="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg 750w, http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2-300x140.jpg 300w" width="360"></a>
    <div class="tt-news-date">
      <span>11</span> Oct
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tt-news-label">
    <span>By: <a>cfbt admin</a></span>
  </div>
  <a class="tt-news-title c-h6" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/">Puppet Workshop</a>
  <div class="simple-text size-4">
    &nbsp; An optional PD session entitled “Making a Bruneian Student Finger Puppet” was held on Wednesday ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to do it with jQuery you can simplify your code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.custom-hover').mouseenter(
      function() {
        $('.tt-news-date,.tt-news-title').css('display', 'block');
      }
    ).mouseleave(
      function() {
        $('.tt-news-date,.tt-news-title').css('display', '');
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```css
.tt-news-date, .tt-news-title {
  display: none;
}
.tt-news-img img {
  background-color: #444;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tt-news">
  <div class="tt-news-top">
    <a class="tt-news-img custom-hover" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/"><img alt="" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" height="168" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px" src="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg" srcset="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2.jpg 750w, http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-2-300x140.jpg 300w" width="360"></a>
    <div class="tt-news-date">
      <span>11</span> Oct
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tt-news-label">
    <span>By: <a>cfbt admin</a></span>
  </div>
  <a class="tt-news-title c-h6" href="http://www.cfbtvideos.org/cfbt/2017/10/11/puppet-workshop/">Puppet Workshop</a>
  <div class="simple-text size-4">
    &nbsp; An optional PD session entitled “Making a Bruneian Student Finger Puppet” was held on Wednesday ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to handle both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to show and hide the special data.

> The image was not loading for me so I needed to set its width and height so I had something to hover over. The CSS related to that is strictly for testing.

Comment: Sorry, question, It can be done in CSS, but may I know how do I do it in jQuery? I wanted to see the difference on how to implement it in both way.

Comment: See the update I added. You can't just use `hover` unless you don't want the special content to stay showing once you hovered over the trigger element. If you want it to go away once you move away from the trigger element then you need to use `mouseleave` as well.

Comment: Got it! That's what I noticed. The content stayed there after I hovered it. I thought it would be the same as the "hover" in CSS where it would disappear after I hovered off the element.

Answer (score 0):

hello as @intervalia said is better with pure css, but to do it in JQuery in your question you have some issues, the item have a inline style 'style="display: block;"' maybe you intention is these elements where not visible so add a class for make them 'display: none', and your selector is wrong change var posthover = $(".custom-hover.custom-hover"); for var posthover = $(".custom-hover");

```
$(function() {
    var posthover = $(".custom-hover");

    $(posthover).hover( function() {
        $(".tt-news-date").css("display", "block");
        $(".tt-news-title").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/zcgpqbag/1/)

hope it helps.